# How to send messages to same set of routes multiple times and execute it in async fashion on different threads concurrently?

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

I have a situation where we need to send a message to the same route multiple times that route will run infinitely such as,

```
from(file://configuration.txt)
.bean(parseToList.class)
.split(body()) // each iteration will have different config data
.to(route://xyz)
.end()


//this will run indefinetly 
from(direct://xyz)
.to(sql:fetch query dynamically based on data)
.choice().when().simple(roucount>0).to(file://destination)
.sleep(3000)
.to(direct://xyz)
```

I need direct:XYZ should be called for every message on a different thread and should run forever. How to achieve this in camel?

*Edit 1:*
I got a suggestion to use seda: instead of direct to enable the async capability. But I also need the route to be transactional, So any suggestion to implement an async and transactional route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for can be implemented with [SEDA](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/seda-component.html) component. `direct:` component is synchronous but SEDA provides async behaviour. Additionally checkout samples in [Camel Examples](https://github.com/apache/camel-examples) repo.

Comment: Does SEDA support transactional behaviour? If not is there any alternative with transaction support?